# parseFloat() Not Working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, parsefloat

I was wondering what am I doing wrong? I am trying to put some numbers into javascript vars and add them but when I uncomment the line that prints the values they are all NaN.

```
<div id="priceDisplayPoolHeating">8.00</div>
<div id="priceDisplayPetFee">7.00</div>
<div id="priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection">4.00</div>
<div id="priceDisplayVacationPackageTotal">9.80</div>
```

```js
function recalculateGrandTotal() {
  var alreadySetCosts = 30.00;

  var thePoolHeatingFeeRounded = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").value);
  var thePetFeeRounded = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPetFee").value);
  var thePropertyDamageProtectionFeeRounded = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection").value);

  var theGrandTotal = alreadySetCosts + thePoolHeatingFeeRounded + thePetFeeRounded + thePropertyDamageProtectionFeeRounded;

  document.getElementById("priceDisplayVacationPackageTotal").innerHTML = theGrandTotal;
  document.write('<br/>The Vars: ' + alreadySetCosts + '<br/>' + thePoolHeatingFeeRounded + '<br/>' + thePetFeeRounded + '<br/>' + thePropertyDamageProtectionFeeRounded + '<br/>' + theGrandTotal);
}
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, it's hard to say.

Comment: Just a sidenote, I'd recommend not prefixing variable names with `the`. It's more concise to write `grandTotal` than `theGrandTotal`.

Comment: The problem is the `"bla bla bla... dummy text"`. I think that needs to be inside the `<script>` tag rather than after it

Comment: Without being totally conscious of it, I think of more unique variable names to prevent confusion or conflict with ported or native code within a larger script/application.

Comment: Woah - what a messy question. Please reduce it to the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: LOL. I had to add some dummy text to post because I got an error about not having enough text explaining my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because div tags don't have a `value`.

```
<div id="priceDisplayPoolHeating" class="priceDisplay">8.00</div>
```

You have to change your JS lines with code like this:

```
document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").value
```

To instead get the text:

```
document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").innerHTML
```

When you're debugging you should try to see what is contained in values like `document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").value`. If you had done that you would have seen it returned `undefined` and `parseFloat(undefined);` returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a value attribute of an element...

```
document.getElementById("priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection").value
```

You need the textContent:

```
document.getElementById("priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection").textContent
```

I hope that helps?